# Manage Form Display - not saving configuration

Tags: forms

i'm working on a pretty big User/register site. Today i created some more fields.
Now i want to order them properly with the "manage form display" settings like i used to but it is not working. 
Everytime i press save the page is reloaded but no changes are made. Yesterday evening everything worked fine.

Is there a maximum of fields you can use?
Or does anyone has an idea what could be the problem here?

I'm really clueless because 12 hours ago it worked just fine for me...

with best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many fields are we talking? Is it hundreds?

I don't believe there is a maximum within Drupal but your server might have a limit. Within the php.ini config file on your web server you should see "max_input_vars"

You could try increasing that and restarting your apache/nginx server to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: `post_max_size` can also be a culprit in extreme cases

Comment: This was the solution for me. I changed max_input_nesting_level = 128, max_input_vars = 2000 and memory_limit = 256M. Now its working again.